# Multi-threading through lots of files

Tags: c++, multithreading, audio

Good evening to everyone. 
*First, sorry for my English, I'm trying to know better this language.*

I've three files:

- **Main.cpp** -> Contain the graphics interface, and the two worker
  thread.
- **Lettore.cpp** -> Contain the functions to reconize the type of
  the file and use the correct library for play the audio, also contain
  the function for stop, play,pause,skip a song.
- **The two audio code library** -> That decode the track and send it to ao for playing.

Now, i'm trying to divide the audio process from the main code. But i don't know how to realize that.
I see C++ 11 reference, i study the condition variable of the pthreded module, but how i can implement this ?

For example, a implement like this in one of the libraries audio files, is correct?

```
//mpg123.c
int playmp3(char* filename,int action)
{
    static mpg123_handle *mh;
    static unsigned char *buffer;
    /*...Many Static Dichiaration.../*
    static long rate;
    char* canzone=filename;
        if (action==0)
        {
            /* Inizialize */
            /*...*/
            /* open the file and get the decoding format */
            mpg123_open(mh,canzone);
            mpg123_getformat(mh, &rate, &channels, &encoding);
            /* set the output format and open the output device */
            format.bits = mpg123_encsize(encoding) * BITS;
            /*...*/
            dev = ao_open_live(driver, &format, NULL);
        }       
        if(action==1)
        {
            /* decode and play */
            while (action==1&&mpg123_read(mh, buffer, buffer_size, &done) == MPG123_OK)
                if((ao_play(dev, (char*)buffer, done)==0)&&action==1)
        }
         if(action==2)
        {
                /* clean up */
                free(buffer);
                ao_close(dev);
                mpg123_close(mh);
            /*...*/
        }
}
```

Like you can see i need extern the code in other files because "playmp3" is write in C and "playother" is write in C++.

**In "Lettore.cpp" how i can control the audio flow ? I can include directly a function of Lettore.cpp in a thread of the main.cpp?**

*Thank you for your time*

*Ps: if this question isn't congruent with the rules i modify this question instantly!*

EDIT: *For clarity I attach also my attempt on Lettore.cpp*

```
//Lettore.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "playother.h"
#include "Lettore.h"
extern "C" {
#include "mpg123.h"
}
bool Audio::isMp3(char * nome)
{
        //Reconize if the file is an mp3.
}
void Audio::inizialize(char * filename)
{
    Audio::currentrack=filename;
    Audio::isOpen=true;
    if (isMp3(Audio::tracciacorrente)){
        playmp3(Audio::currentrack,0);
    }else{
        playmusic(Audio::currentrack,0);
    }
}
void Audio::play()
{
    if (isMp3(Audio::currentrack)){
        playmp3(Audio::currentrack,1);
    }else{
        playmusic(Audio::currentrack,1);
    }
}
void Audio::close()
{
    if (isMp3(Audio::currentrack)){
        playmp3(Audio::currentrack,2);
    }else{
        playmusic(Audio::currentrack,2);
    }
    Audio::currentrack=NULL;
    Audio::isOpen=false;
}
void Audio::pause()
{
    if (isMp3(Audio::currentrack)){
        playmp3(Audio::currentrack,4);
    }else{
        playmusic(Audio::currentrack,4);
    }
}
bool Audio::get_openstatus()
{
    return Audio::isOpen;
}
```

Now the question is the same: If this is the correct implementation of the two files, what should I write about main.cpp order to use these files?

Comment: What does this question have to do with threads? It seems like you are asking for design advice on how to decouple your audio C Libraries from `Lettore.cpp`.

Comment: As specified by the final questions, I understand the thread of the C + + but do not know how to use them over this code to make an audio player that runs off from the main.

Obviously I do **not** need a source code ready to use, just the guidelines to understand how to "spin off" in another process the audio library, communicating through a third file: `Lettore.cpp`
What I do not understand is a secure implementation of the three files in multi-thetering...
_I hope I explained_